# Why does my function stop working inside the API?

Tags: javascript, api, express, filter

I have an array of objects like the following

```
const statsData = 
[ 
  {
    "id": 7175,
    "shots": 0,
    "goals": 0,
    "tackles": 0
  },
  {
    "id": 1145,
    "shots": 1,
    "goals": 2,
    "tackles": 1
  }
]
```

I'm trying to filter by id and return the object(s) which contain the id, like below...

```
const data = (id) => {
    return statData.filter(obj => Object.values(obj).includes(id))
  }

  console.log(data(id))
```

This happens inside an express API route which looks like so...

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
const statData = require('../public/stat-data.json')

router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
  const {id} = req.body

  const data = (id) => {
    return statData.filter(obj => Object.values(obj).includes(id))
  }

  console.log(data(id))
  res.json(data(id));
});

module.exports = router;
```

The filter function works fine outside of the API. The API is working fine in as much as the route is working and I'm receiving the id and able to send a response to the front end.
However the function always returns an empty array from inside the API call, and will respond with an empty array to the front end.
Why?!

Comment: You're not passing the result as an argument to `res.json()`: `res.json(data(id))`

Comment: Sorry that was just me not writing the question correctly, I'll update the question now. However I did actually pass the function with argument into res.json() and it returns an empty array. The console.log(data(id)) also returns an empty array

Comment: What's being returned in req.body?

Comment: Why are you using `includes` instead of just checking `obj.id == id`?

Comment: What is `typeof id`?

Comment: Thanks Barmar! The console log showed it as a number but I did typeof and sure enough it was a string. Problem solved. Was banging my head against the wall that!